# checking scrolltop of a div on window's scroll event

Tags: jquery

Please refer this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USDFn/)

I want to change css of div #fixed when its scrolltop is less than 50. but it is not checking the condition  `(fixedscrolltop < 50)`  at all.

the #fixed div should be repositioned when its offset is less than 50. not when the scroll event occurs

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.scrollTop()` instead of `.offset()` to get your wanted effect.

```
$('document').ready(function () {

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var fixedscrolltop = $(window).scrollTop();
        height = $('#fixed').position().top;
        if (fixedscrolltop >= height-50) 
        {
          $('#fixed').css({
              position: 'fixed',
              top: '0'
          });
        }
    });
});
```

you read the `position().top` of your element and subtract its `scrollTop` with the value you want. In your case `50`

See the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/USDFn/9/)**

Comment: No. the #fixed div should be repositioned when its offset is less than 50. not when the scroll event occurs.